Singular values and eigenvalues of matrices with coefficients in an ultrametric field
Consider a complete ultrametric field $(\Omega,|.|)$. We endow $M_n(\Omega)$ with the maximum norm. Given a matrix $G\in M_n(\Omega)$, recall that the singular values $\sigma_1\geq\dots \geq \sigma_n$ of $G$ are the none negative real number such that the product $\sigma_1\dots\sigma_i$ corresponds to the maximum of the absolute values of $i\times i$ minors of $G$. In particular, we have $\sigma_1=||G||$ and $\sigma_1\dots\sigma_n=|det(G)|$. Let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $G$ counted with multiplicity such that $|\lambda_1|\geq\dots\geq |\lambda_n|$. Suppose that $i$ first eigenvalues coincide with $i$ first singulars values of $G$, and let $H\in M_n(\Omega)$ such that $||H||<\sigma_i$.
Question:
Are the absolute values of the $i$ first eigenvalues of $G+H$ coincide with the absolute values of the $i$ first eigenvalues $G$?
